# Cannot bypass Dynamic status cache for my APIs in Cloudflare

Tags: caching, cloudflare

After defining the following configuration to avoid dynamic caching for an API : [Cloudflare for your API](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200504045-Using-Cloudflare-with-your-API)

My calls are still in a Dynamic cache status. You can see the received reponse headers :

```sh
access-control-allow-methods: GET,OPTIONS
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400, h3-28=":443"; ma=86400, h3-27=":443"; ma=86400
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-ray: 698eeac5ae5640cf-CDG
client-control: max-age=43200, s-max-age=43200
content-encoding: br
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 04 Oct 2021 13:57:03 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
expires: 0
pragma: no-cache
server: cloudflare
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
vary: Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: DENY
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

Here's the configuration i've done

[image]

Do you find a way to get a 'BYPASS' cache [Clouflare Status Headers](https://getfishtank.ca/blog/cloudflare-cdn-cf-cache-status-headers-explained)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to avoid having your API calls cached, then the above page rule looks correct. You are using a `Cache Level` directive to `Bypass` the caching logic.

This means that all the calls matching the URL pattern will always be pulled from your origin server. This is confirmed by the `cf-cache-status` response header valued with `DYNAMIC`

From the [documentation](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/default-cache-behavior#cloudflare-cache-responses)

> DYNAMIC: Cloudflare does not consider the asset eligible to cache and your Cloudflare settings do not explicitly instruct Cloudflare to cache the asset. Instead, the asset was requested from the origin web server.

The response header `cf-cache-status` can also have a value of `BYPASS`, but this happens in other scenarios (also described in the documentation)

Comment: yeah, it seems only `BYPASS` status is used for static assets. Thks